# How to "start a node agent" in Websphere?

Tags: websphere

How do you "start a node agent" in Websphere ?
The error message is:
"Server cannot be started because the node agent for server x_server on node wasdev1Node01 is not active."
(I am on the dev server.)

Also, the app logon procedure errored because of "Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. ". While trying to start the JINDY I got the node server message.

When I try to start the application server:

"Server cannot be started because the node agent for server wasdev1 on node wasdev1Node01 is not active."

Starting the Node Agent from the console:
"The node agent on node wasdev1Node01 must be started to perform the restart operation. Node agents in stopped state can not be started from the console."

You would need to start the node agent from command line as below.

WAS_HOME/profiles/YOUR_PROFILE_NAME/bin/startNode.cmd (I do not have this command.)

Comment: What version of WebSphere do you have installed?

Comment: It should be `startNode.bat` file. If you dont have it you are looking in the wrong profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have the `startNode.sh` or `startNode.cmd` command linked in your profile's `bin` directory if your profile was created from a Network Deployment installation and your node had been federated into a cell.  If your profile is a standalone application profile that has **not** been federated, there should not be a `startNode` command available.

Comment: Just the clarify, the startNode script will still be available, but it will fail if you try to run it.

Comment: Just FYI, in my case the script is at:
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/startNode.sh

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error you are running ND not standalone/base version. You cannot start the nodeagent from the console (only stop and restart.
startNode.sh(.bat) from command line to start the nodeagent. Make sure nodeagent process/pid is not present. As for the applicatin servers defined under the node, they need Location Daemon Service running on the node to start.

Comment: Location Daemon Service - how do you do that?

Comment: LDS runs inside the nodeagent, You can look for Location Daemon Service not running inside the JVM logs to tell you that Node is down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the error appears only thing you need to start nodeagent from your appsrv profile/bin with command prompt only if you install on windows environment.

you should open as command prompt as administrator privileges and then go to profile path and run startNode.bat or .sh .